# What is the Difference between VM image and Snapshot in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have gone through multiple documentation from Azure Docs.However, dint get the exact difference between them in terms of Implementation, Purpose etc.
Need one of the scenario/suggestion where I can get implement this!

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12540 by Karishma Tiwari (MSFT)

A VM Image contains an OS disk, which has been generalized and needs to be provisioned during deployment time. OS Images today are generalized. This is meant to be used as a “model” to quickly stamp out similar virtual machines, such as scaling out a front-end to your application in production or spinning up and tearing down similar development and test environments quickly.

A Snapshot contains an OS disk, which is already provisioned. It is similar to a disk today in that it is “ready-to-use”, but unlike a disk, the VHDs of a Snapshot are treated as read-only and copied when deploying a new virtual machine. A snapshot is a copy of the virtual machine's disk file at a given point in time, **meant to be used to deploy a VM to a good known point in time**, such as check pointing a developer machine, before performing a task which may go wrong and render the virtual machine useless.

Comment: Snapshots are not tied to VMs. And they are not tied to OS disks. They are a feature of Azure Storage block & page blobs. They are also available for managed disks, but not tied to OS disks.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, It seems we are talking about 2 different snapshots. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk

"A snapshot is a full, read-only copy of a virtual hard drive (VHD). You can take a snapshot of an OS or data disk VHD to use as a backup, or to troubleshoot virtual machine (VM) issues.

If you are going to use the snapshot to create a new VM, we recommend that you cleanly shut down the VM before taking a snapshot, to clear out any processes that are in progress."