# Azure VHD Image vs VM Snapshots

Tags: azure, azure-vm

Where are VHD images stored in Azure? When a customer creates a generalized VM image and uses this image to redeploy other VMs, where is the generalized image stored?

If I execute the command:

```
az vm create \
  --name MyVMFromImage \
   --image MyVMImage \
   --admin-username azureuser
```

(where is --image being fetched from).

Also, what is the difference between creating a VM image vs. taking a Disk snapshot and redeploying the VM using these two options. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Where are VHD images stored in Azure? When a customer creates a
> generalized VM image and uses this image to redeploy other VMs, where
> is the generalized image stored?

A generalized virtual machine (VM) is stored as either a managed disk or an unmanaged disk in a storage account.

> If I execute the command:
>
> az vm create \   --name MyVMFromImage \    --image MyVMImage \
> --admin-username azureuser
>
> (where is --image being fetched from).

There are the images provided by Azure for you to choose from. If you run the below command, it would give a list of all available image options. Valid image format is "Publisher:Offer:Sku:Version".

`az vm image list`

You can find more details in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create

> Also, what is the difference between creating a VM image vs. taking a
> Disk snapshot and redeploying the VM using these two options.

Please refer to a similar SO question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55076908/5344880

If you are interested in how to create a snapshot, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk

Since you were asking about VM images, there is an option to store in Shared Image Galley as well. Please check here for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries

Hope this helps.